# update a value in one collection if the value is pushed to another collection in meteor

Tags: meteor

I have `posts` and `postdata` collection.

In `posts` i'm saving the post and in `postsdata`  I have comments array `postdata`

```
posts={_id:"xxx",name:"sss",contnent:"sfsfsdSFs",commentCount:0}

postdata={post_id:"xxx",comments:["aaa","Ssss","sfsdf"]}
```

whenver there is a push to `comments` array in `postdata`, I want to automatically increment the `commentsCount` variable in `posts` collection.

How to do it?Is there any best practice to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having two separated collections, you can have one single collection "post" and put your comments array in it:

```
posts = {_id:"xxx",name:"sss",contnent:"sfsfsdSFs",commentCount:3, comments:["aaa","Ssss","sfsdf"]}
```

If you have to separate into two collections, make a server side method to handle the insertion of new comments, so whenever there is a new comment, push it to the postdata comment array and increase the commentCount of post by 1.